# Firebase console gives error "Unexpected .read"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write the rules from Firebase console. But getting errors.
Here is my very basic structure. Please help me.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      ".read": "auth.uid== User1"
    }
 }
}
```

**Error:** Error saving rules - Line 4: Unexpected '".read"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up [Firebase Realtime Database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) with [Firebase Cloud Firestore rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  If you're following examples for Firestore, don't use examples from Realtime Database.  For example, there is no ".read" rule in Firestore.  Please read the documentation to get acquainted with the rules.

Comment: Ohh, I see, Thank you.